# Xbee Factory -Hardware reset without serial communication

Tags: xbee, reset

I'm using "XBee 802.15.4 Module" 
After successful connection with X-cut & made a "+++" it responded "Ok" 
Then is stopped working .... 
I tried to reconnect to it again & failed .. it no longer accept a serial communication. 
I searched many topics for this problem , trying to find a solution for reset, specially a Hardware reset ... didn't find any !

So my questions are:

1- "There a method to make a reset for it & restore to factory default with hardware & without serial communication " ?

2- "How I can be positive  that the module is "burned down" & no longer working .." ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Instructable, [Configuring Xbees](http://www.instructables.com/id/Changing-Xbee-Baud-Rates/) article, [Un-Bricking](http://www.instructables.com/id/Changing-Xbee-Baud-Rates/step5/Un-bricking-a-frozen-Xbee/) step:

> 1. Take the module out of the interface board.
> 2. Connect the interface board to the computer.
> 3. Open X-CTU make sure Baud Rate is set to 9600
> 4. Go to "Modem Configuration"
> 5. Put a check in the "Always update firmware" box
> 6. Select proper modem from drop down menu,
> 7. Select proper function set and firmware version from drop down menus.
> 8. Click on the "Write" button. After a few seconds of trying to read the modem, you will get an Info box that says Action Needed. At this point, CAREFULLY insert the module into the interface board.
> 9. You may get the info box again a short while after, just use the reset button on the interface board.